# Create dynamic object and JSON encode it

Tags: php, json, pdo

I have the following code:

```
while ($row = $psql - > fetch()) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $psql - > columnCount(); $i++) {
        $col = $psql - > getColumnMeta($i);
        array_push($json, array($col['name'] = > $row[$i]));
    }
}
echo "var data = ".json_encode($json).";";
```

Which is producing this output:

```
var data = [{"id":"3"},{"id2":"1"},{"sec":"1"},{"cat":"1"},{"term":"Teste"},{"sTerm":""}];
```

But in order to import that data I need the output to look like this:

```
var data = [{id:"3",id2:"1",sec:"1",cat:"1",term:"Teste",sTerm:""}];
```

(Each data inside `{...}` is a row.

Is there any way I could do this besides building the string manually?

Thank you

Comment: there is a much better answer there than the one you've accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do away with all that non-sense about reading column metadata.  What you are ultimately after is an array of objects.  So you can simplify that down to this:

```
while ($row_obj = $psql->fetch_object()) {
    $json[] = $row_obj;
}
echo "var data = ".json_encode($json).";";
```

Here, `$row_obj` would be an object with column name for properties which store the associated values.

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do it:

```
while ($row = $psql->fetch()) {
    $line = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $psql-> columnCount(); $i++) {
        $col = $psql-> getColumnMeta($i);
        $line[$col['name']] = $row[$i];
    }
    array_push($json,$line);
}
echo "var data = ".json_encode($json).";";
```

Comment: I will as soon as it lets me. You were too fast I guess... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array union operator, according to the docs here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php i haven't tried it, but since `$json` is an array you should be able to concatenate it in this way.

```
$json = array();
while ($row = $psql - > fetch()) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $psql - > columnCount(); $i++) {
        $col = $psql - > getColumnMeta($i);
        $json = $json + array($col['name'] = > $row[$i]));
    }
}
echo "var data = ".json_encode($json).";";
```

Comment: Did you just change `array_push($json` for `$json[]=`? Isn't that exactly the same? EDIT: PS I didn't downvote - I left a constructive comment instead, which is the idea.

Comment: $json[] *is* the same. Didn't downvote either though

Comment: @Popnoodles well, i tried again with the array union operator but i was too slow

Comment: @r3wt that wasn't really the issue, it was about which data to assign not how to append to the array. Even though it's a wrong answer, I've fixed that -1 because it's not right to downvote without a comment. Perhaps it was the person who also begged for a green tick. #ugh

Comment: @Popnoodles how did you draw that conclusion from the OP? it looks like to me he was getting a multidimensional array and wanted a single dimensional array instead. Admittedly i'm a world class idiot so what do i know really..

Comment: I reached that conclusion given that there is an answer marked with a big green tick that addresses that.